How to automatically set an IRB configuration across all environments for a specific rails app?
I'd like to set an IRB configuration across an app (all environments, including production) so I don't have to run it every time I use the rails console. The specific configuration isn't that important, but it's:
IRB.conf[:USE_PAGER] = false 

What I've tried
I thought it would be as simple as:
# config/initializers/console.rb
Rails.application.console do
  IRB.conf[:USE_PAGER] = false
end

but when I open the rails console
IRB.conf[:USE_PAGER]
# => true

confirming that it hasn't set (or was set but was overridden).
Note

I considered using a ~/.irbrc file but that wouldn't work across multiple machines (e.g. the configuration should be applied in production, not just locally)

I notice someone asked how to include .irbrc in the app itself. When I attempted the answer, my bin directory doesn't have a file called console (just bundle, dev, rails, rake, setup)




you should be able to add .irbrc file into your project directory, no extra steps required.

@Alex tried it and you are 100% right. Thank you very much. If you would like to make it an answer, please do

@Alex I added a note on the linked question and attributed you

You can add .irbrc into your project. There are multiple locations that a configuration file can be loaded from, including the current directory, which can be your project. Although, the docs say "the first file found", all the files found will be loaded:

The path to the configuration file is the first found among:

The value of variable $IRBRC, if defined.
The value of variable $XDG_CONFIG_HOME/irb/irbrc, if defined.
File $HOME/.irbrc, if it exists.
File $HOME/.config/irb/irbrc, if it exists.
File .irbrc in the current directory, if it exists.
File irb.rc in the current directory, if it exists.
File _irbrc in the current directory, if it exists.
File $irbrc in the current directory, if it exists.


https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/master/IRB.html#module-IRB-label-Configuration+File
